# Save new plist file with filename equal to the value from a string variable

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, plist

I am creating an iPhone application that will write the application data to a plist file, in which one of the text fields contains ProjName.text.

How can I save a plist file with the name of ProjName.text.plist.

For example, if the value of ProjName is "Servers" how do I save out of my array to a "Servers.plist" file?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    NSString *documentsPath  = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *destination  = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", textfield.text];

   [fileData writeToFile:destination atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [self savePlist:@"Servers" fromArray:yourArray]; //or
// [self savePlist:textField.text fromArray:yourArray];

#pragma mark - plist
- (NSString *) getFilePathForPlist:(NSString *) plistName {
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",plistName]];
}

-(void) savePlist:(NSString *)plistName fromArray:(NSMutableArray *)array {
    [array writeToFile:[self getFilePathForPlist:plistName] atomically:YES];
}
```